# Working with strings and objects

Tags: scala, traits

I think my problem is pretty straight forward - I have a text file made out of 'E' and 'B' symbols, for example:

```
EBBEBBB BBEB
         E
BEB BEB  B
B
```

Now i want to get this data. When i use it, i don't want it to be in a form of strings because you can pass anything that would not work, for example something like a number or any other invalid symbol. That's why i figured i could create some case objects that extends a single trait(like shown below). Problem is, I don't know how i should CORRECTLY convert my string data to that particular data structure that I made:

```
sealed trait EB
case object E extends EB
case object B extends EB

case class EB_Text(data: Vector[EB])

def convertText(fileData: Vector[String]) : EB_Text = {
  //Match each symbol and check if it's 'E' or 'B' ?
  //If i find an invalid symbol here, what do i return? Should i return AN Option here?
}
```

Thank you! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the function in the following way

```
def convertText(fileData: Vector[String]) : EB_Text = {
EB_Text(fileData.map{
  singleLine =>
    singleLine.replaceAll(" ","").toUpperCase().collect{
      case 'E' => E
      case 'B' => B
    }
}.flatten)
}
```

You do not need to make any modifications to the case objects that you had defined earlier. You can keep them as it is

```
sealed trait EB
case object E extends EB
case object B extends EB

case class EB_Text(data: Vector[EB])
```

On invoking the function with the following input, you will get the output as

```
val input = Vector("EBBEBBB BBEB","         E","BEB BEB  B","  B ")
convertText(input)
```

you will get the output as

```
res0: EB_Text = EB_Text(Vector(E, B, B, E, B, B, B, B, B, E, B, E, B, E, B, B, E, B, B, B))
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct and returning an options sounds like the right thing to do. If you don't need the option though (or any other information related to the convert operation, e.g. the underlying string) there is no reason to construct it.

I also don't think that is necessary to wrap the result in a case class.

```
    def convertText(fileData: Vector[String]) : Vector[EB] = {
        for (s <- fileData if s == "E" || s == "B") yield {
            if (s == "E") E
            else B
        }
    }
```